# Search Filter in nested ng-repeat in a list and Hide parents that don't have children

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WYnB9npQAl55BmF6lK0F)

> I wanted to filter the items in a dynamic list names that is fetched from json files. here my requirement is to hide the parents that don't have children i'm sharing my sample code here.. in my program the parent list is still showing.

## index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myItemsApp">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>dynamic title</title>

      <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

      <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
      <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

      <form >
           <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="getlist" placeholder="Search Docs..">
            </div>
      </form>


      <div ng-controller=NavController>
        <h3>Load title dynamically</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="(key,item) in itemDetails">
                {{key}}
                <li ng-repeat="i in item | filter:getlist"><a class="list-group-item" ng-click="select(i)" >{{i.title}}</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <h2>Title_from json: {{selected.title}}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

## script.js

```
var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', []);

myItemsApp.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function($http){
  var itemsFactory ={
    itemDetails: function() {
      return $http(
      {
        url: "action.json",
        method: "GET",
      })      
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
        });
      }
    };
    return itemsFactory;

}]);


myItemsApp.controller('NavController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory', function($scope, itemsFactory){
  var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

    promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.itemDetails = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
    $scope.select = function(item) {
      $scope.selected = item;
    }
    $scope.selected = {};
}]);
```

## action.json

```
{

   "product": [{
         "title": "Product View",
         "path": "test1"

      },

      {
         "title": "Product Add",
         "path": "2"

      },
      {
         "title": "Product Update",
         "path": "test3"


      },

      {
         "title": "Product delete",
         "path": "test4"

      }
   ],

   "page": [{
      "title": "About us"
   }]

}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WYnB9npQAl55BmF6lK0F :- my plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="(key,item) in itemDetails" >
        {{result.length > 0 ?key : ''}}
        <li ng-repeat="i in result = (item | filter:getlist)"><a class="list-group-item" ng-click="select(i)" >{{i.title}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/x3EmAhBMgqdPawZxGC4I?p=preview)

Comment: i did some modifications in my code i added some glymphicons for parent and child but now while searching the parent is hidden but the glymph icon is still showing i'm adding the updated plunker plese help me http://plnkr.co/edit/WYnB9npQAl55BmF6lK0F?p=preview

Comment: Try use `ng-show` directive. like this `<i ng-show="result.length > 0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks "></i>`